# Django doesn't find CSS files for admin pages using uWSGI

Tags: python, django, uwsgi, static-content

Even if I followed the [official instructions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/uwsgi/), when I start a Django test site using uWSGI, CSS files for the admin interface are not loaded. If I open the URL of a CSS file, for example `http://localhost:8443/static/admin/css/base.css`, I get a 404 error. I searched for the local file and I guess its path is `/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/base.css`; so I also tried to run uwsgi as root, but nothing changed.

I have no problem using `python3 manage.py runserver`. If I open `http://localhost:8000/static/admin/css/base.css`, the file is loaded in the browser, and the style is applied to the admin page.

This is the command I execute in bash:

```
uwsgi --ini ~/.uwsgi/conf/django.ini --set-placeholder project_name=mysite --set-placeholder port=8443
```

and this is the content of django.ini:

```
[uwsgi]
module = %(project_name).wsgi:application
https = :%(port),/usr/local/nginx/conf/server.crt,/usr/local/nginx/conf/server.key,HIGH
strict = true
chdir = /home/marco/django-projects/%(project_name)
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=%(project_name).settings
socket = /home/marco/.uwsgi/%(project_name).socket
pidfile = /home/marco/.uwsgi/%(project_name).pid
daemonize = /home/marco/.uwsgi/%(project_name).log
master = true
enable-threads = true
harakiri = 20
max-requests = 5000
vacuum = true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Official deployment docs (independently by the WSGI server) do not cover serving static files (that is generally managed by the webserver). The right docs are here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/deployment/

eventually serving static files is pretty easy with uWSGI:

http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/StaticFiles.html

but if you can do it in nginx it is better

Comment: Thank you, I also followed this simple tutorial: https://uwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html , even if it does not remember to add to PROJECT/settings.py the line `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")`and run `python3 manage.py collectstatic`.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. My nginx server on Centos 7.6 can't access to static folder in path `/home/user/app/mysyte/static/`. In `/var/log/nginx/error.log` same error

```
open() "/home/user/app/mysyte/static/*.css" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

For solving and understanding this problem `:=*`

1. run command `getenforce`
2. if enforcing - `cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep nginx`

for me string with errrors looks like

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1558033633.723:201): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=7758 comm="nginx" name="responsive.css" dev="dm-0" ino=17312394 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1558033633.723:201): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=no exit=-13 a0=564f710dd55d a1=800 a2=0 a3=68632f656d6f682f items=0 ppid=7757 pid=7758 auid=4294967295 uid=998 gid=996 euid=998 suid=998 fsuid=998 egid=996 sgid=996 fsgid=996 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="nginx" exe="/usr/sbin/nginx" subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)
```

copy id of audit msg `1558033633.723:201`

3. run command `grep yours_audit_id /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2why`

output for me

```
[root@uwsgi ~]# grep 1558034479.384:221 /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2why
type=AVC msg=audit(1558034479.384:221): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=7758 comm="nginx" name="responsive.css" dev="dm-0" ino=17312394 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

        Was caused by:
        The boolean httpd_read_user_content was set incorrectly.
        Description:
        Allow httpd to read user content

        Allow access by executing:
        # setsebool -P httpd_read_user_content 1
```

So as you can see answer here `setsebool -P httpd_read_user_content 1` when you run this command you see your static content

Comment: Really, it didn't work for me on fedora 37 with django, gunicron and nginx.